# pandas series to unique binary indicators

Tags: pandas, binary, indicator

Here is what I have

```
>>> s = pd.Series([0,2,1,0], ['t1','t2','t3','t4'])
>>> s
t1    0
t2    2
t3    1
t4    0
dtype: int64
```

I want an output which looks like this with binary indicators for each value as pandas dataframe:

```
value  t1   t2   t3   t4
    0   1    0    0    1
    1   0    0    1    0
    2   0    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need `get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(s)

#    0  1  2
#t1  1  0  0
#t2  0  0  1
#t3  0  1  0
#t4  1  0  0
```

You can further transpose it if you need it in the other way:

```
pd.get_dummies(s).T

#   t1  t2  t3  t4
#0   1   0   0   1
#1   0   0   1   0
#2   0   1   0   0
```